# Manipulando datas

Tags: java, data

Tenho dúvida sobre os passos para manipular datas.

Os passos abaixo estão ok? Posso iniciar os estudos?

- Tenho o atributo `Date` e quero inserir 2 dias.
- Converto `Date` em `String`.
- Converter `String` em `Calendar`.
- Faço o código para manipular a data obtida.
- Converto de `Calendar` para `String`.
- Converto de `String` para `Date`.
- Salvo.

porque se eu tentar declarar como `Calendar` quando salvo da esse erro?

> Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from

Código para mais detalhes:

```
// data em que o dinheiro foi entregue
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataEmprestimo;
```

se eu colocar `private Calendar dataEmprestimo`, dá o erro mencionado acima.

Comment: Pode adicionar a stacktrace completa? Porque este codigo não está fazendo muito sentido com o erro.

Comment: Desculpe se nao consigo me expressar bem. mas tentarei explicar aqui.

Comment: Quando tenta executar, estoura uma pilha de erros? Se sim, adicione ela na pergunta, fica mais facil localizar a origem.

Comment: Mas porque você está trocando o tipo para Calendar? A anotação em cima indica que é Date, e não calendar.

Comment: Estou  com duas duvidas.
1º se o passo a passo para manipular a Date esta correta.
2º porque se eu inserir Calendar ao inves de Date da erro: 

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Calendar to Date] with root cause

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Calendar to Date

Comment: se eu remover  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) da certo? por pra calendar?

Comment: Dá erro porque são tipos diferentes, e sua anotação antes do campo diz que se trata de um campo Date.

Comment: Removi  a anotação e deu certo, começou a aparecer uma luz aqui.....
Se nao for pedir muito, estudando ele pediu para colocar a anotação acima, porque ele pediu isso? retira-la implica em que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar a API de Java 8 fica mais fácil para manipular datas

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
LocalDate dataInicio;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
LocalDate data;
```

Em teu objeto só recuperar o campo LocalDate e executar

```
 objeto.getData().plusDays(1)
```

//Acrescenta um dia

Comment: Iniciei o estudo com LocalDate e a data esta sendo salva aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770703000007e1060278. 
se eu incluir @jsonFormat da erro Field error in object 'emprestimo' on field 'primeiraEmprestimo': rejected value [09/06/2017]; codes [typeMismatch.emprestimo.primeiraEmprestimo,typeMismatch.primeiraEmprestimo,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMe

Comment: é porque vc esta usando o formato dd/mm/yyyy, só troca o formato para que seja igual ou muda tua data para que tenha o formato que declaro